# How to create sound notes in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, audio

Is there a command that we can make our Delphi application to emule sound where we can choose the numeric tone and duration just like in basic?

Comment: Something like   Windows.Beep(Frequenz,Duration_in_ms); ?

Comment: Who down voted? That's a bit harsh...

Comment: If you try Beep, delphi says it has no parameter because it finds the beep function from system unit. You have to specify thw winApi.Windows.beep function to get the proper tone capabilities. Thank you guys!

Comment: Some people in this great site thinks that what thay already know should not be asked. It is just for top level questions. Unfortunately.

Comment: just to avoid misunderstandings, I did not downvote, just was sure that someone would provide a better answer as @AndreasRejbrand did.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To produce a pure sine tone, you can use

```
Windows.Beep(400, 1000)
```

which will sound a 400 Hz pure sine tone for a duration of 1000 milliseconds.

If you want to play a real instrument (piano, guitar, or any of the 125 (?) other options), you can use MIDI. Simply use the `MMSystem` unit and do

```
var
  mo: HMIDIOUT;

const
  MIDI_NOTE_ON = $90;
  MIDI_NOTE_OFF = $80;
  MIDI_CHANGE_INSTRUMENT = $C0;

function MIDIEncodeMessage(Msg, Param1, Param2: byte): integer;
begin
  result := Msg + (Param1 shl 8) + (Param2 shl 16);
end;

procedure NoteOn(NewNote, NewIntensity: byte);
begin
  midiOutShortMsg(mo, MIDIEncodeMessage(MIDI_NOTE_ON, NewNote, NewIntensity));
end;

procedure NoteOff(NewNote, NewIntensity: byte);
begin
  midiOutShortMsg(mo, MIDIEncodeMessage(MIDI_NOTE_OFF, NewNote, NewIntensity));
end;

procedure SetInstrument(NewInstrument: byte);
begin
  midiOutShortMsg(mo, MIDIEncodeMessage(MIDI_CHANGE_INSTRUMENT, NewInstrument, 0));
end;

procedure InitMIDI;
begin
  midiOutOpen(@mo, 0, 0, 0, CALLBACK_NULL);
  midiOutShortMsg(mo, MIDIEncodeMessage(MIDI_CHANGE_INSTRUMENT, 0, 0));
end;
```

After you have initialised the MIDI system, you can try

```
NoteOn(50, 127);
Sleep(500);
SetInstrument(60);
NoteOn(60, 127);
Sleep(500);
NoteOff(60, 127);
SetInstrument(80);
NoteOn(70, 127);
Sleep(500);
NoteOff(70, 127);
SetInstrument(90);
NoteOn(80, 127);
Sleep(500);
NoteOff(80, 127);
SetInstrument(100);
NoteOn(90, 127);
Sleep(500);
NoteOff(90, 127);
SetInstrument(12);
NoteOn(40, 127);
Sleep(1000);
NoteOff(40, 127);
```

MIDI programming is *so* underrated!

[Compiled demo EXE](http://privat.rejbrand.se/AFewMIDINotes.exe)

Comment: *MIDI programming is so underrated!* Yes, because who would like to hear such sound :-) [+1 for Windows.Beep]

Comment: @TLama: Are you serious? I think it sounds beautiful, and it is very simple to create beautiful and interesting sounds. [And MIDI files take no space!]

Comment: Yes, since I've been a live DJ (far away from just playing CDs), my expectance for a sound are different than MIDI ;-)

Comment: MIDI is the introductory level to musical production. It's on an instrument level, and should only be considered when simulating a few raw instruments. However, true production comes from much more advanced mechanisms to tweak the sound, such as synthesizers and filters.

Comment: @Jerry et al. I know. I just think MIDI programming is a lot of fun! At least I can spend hours playing with it! And the results, in my view, are often very impressive.

Comment: When we apply those effects like reverberation it sounds great!

Comment: In Delphi 10: Winapi.Windows.Beep(400, 1000);

Comment: @Mahan: I still use `Beep(400, 1000)` in Delphi 10 (and 11), since I have set my unit aliases/namespace prefixes (or whatever they are called) to make `Winapi.Windows` implicit.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I've downloaded the "compiled demo EXE" and it plays nicely; but coudn't do the same with the snippet you pasted above. Can you please put the source code of demo on gist or something? Thanks a lot